# Create repeating section RDL report

Tags: c#, .net, rdl

I am new to rdl reports and I have to create a report in which there are departments, under each department there are category and there are orders for different category. 
So there is a section with header as department name then category name and beneath category we have order list. This section has to be repeated for all the department. Can you guide me how to repeate a particularly designed section in rdl report.

I am new so I don't know what need to be shared for rdl with you. Please let me know the info required.

Answer (score 0):

YOU JUST REFER THE GROUPING CONCEPT IN SSRS, RDL..
1:AT FIRST YOU CREATE THE GROUP FOR DEPARTMENT
2:DEPONDS ON THAT DEPARTMENT YOU CREATE ANTHOR GROUP FOR category 
THIS SHOW YOUR REPOR NICE......